# Recyclerview Single row selectable

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have `RecyclerView` with clickable function, but I want it should be single row selectable, like in `ListView` we have choice mode.

```
@Override
public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.player_row, null);
    RecyclerViewHolder viewHolder = new RecyclerViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Players player = mPlayerList.get(position);
    holder.name.setText(player.getSquadPlayerName());

    holder.itemView.setTag(player);


}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mPlayerList.size();
}


public class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public CustomTextView name;


    public RecyclerViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        name = (CustomTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);




    }


}
```

Full row is clickable. How to achieve single selectable?

Answer (score 0):

```
    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getActivity(), recyclerView, new ClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                        drawerListener.onDrawerItemSelected(view, position);
                        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(containerView);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

                    }
                }));
public interface FragmentDrawerListener {
        void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position);
    }

static class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

        private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
        private ClickListener clickListener;

        public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context,
                final RecyclerView recyclerView,
                final ClickListener clickListener) {
            this.clickListener = clickListener;
            gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context,
                    new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                            return true;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                            View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(
                                    e.getX(), e.getY());
                            if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                                clickListener.onLongClick(child,
                                        recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

            View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
            if (child != null && clickListener != null
                    && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
                clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildPosition(child));
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
        }
    }
```

Comment: where is selection stuff

Comment: When you click any item then call "addOnItemTouchListener"

Comment: when u unselecting selected row

Comment: i am  not understand what you  say

Comment: i cant use addOnItemTouchListener as other stuff in that adatr class can give some snippent in my given code

Comment: You need to  user addOnitemTouchListener in MainClass not adapter see this is example in  this Link      http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/

Comment: i got it that  but view will return for one postion not viewgroup or all view holder

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.player_row, null);
    RecyclerViewHolder viewHolder = new RecyclerViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewHolder holder, final int position) {
     Players player = mPlayerList.get(position);
    holder.name.setText(player.getSquadPlayerName());

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new Listener(position,player));


}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mPlayerList.size();
}
class Listener implements OnClickListener {

Players data;
int position;
        listener(int position, Players data) {
            this.position = position;
        this.data = data;
        }

        @SuppressLint("UseValueOf")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO do whatecer you want to do.

        }
    }

public class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public CustomTextView name;
View itemView;

    public RecyclerViewHolder( View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        name = (CustomTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
this.itemView = itemView;



    }


}
```

Comment: where are u handling row clicks? like only one row

Comment: In Listener  class you can write your code to perform any event

Comment: but in this i am not getting reference al views

Comment: I am not getting u properly this will give you reference of all view  according to position. Listener call work as like a callback for all views

Comment: public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO do whatecer you want to do.

        } v is current only na

Comment: it is working like call back and create a separate instance for separate list item with unique position and unique data item it perform operation on unique item .Please try  this once

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99469/discussion-between-rohit-heera-and-andro).